# If statement for inclusive permission check

Tags: logic

I'm having a little trouble writing a specific if statement that needs to check a kind of cumulative permission, and an analogy to it would be like this:

- Employees have 2 attributes: Alpha and Beta;
- Alpha could be `X` or `NULL` and Beta is either `A`, `B`, `C` or `NULL`;
- To check if a employee can enter in a particular room we need to check if that room could be accessible to that particular employee:

  - Rooms have a yes or no attribute for Alpha attribute and each value of Beta attribute (Alpha=X [`Y`/`N`], Beta=A [`Y`/`N`], Beta=B [`Y`/`N`], Beta=C [`Y`/`N`]);
  - If an employee has attribute Alpha set to `X`, Beta set to anything and the room has [Alpha=X -> `Yes`] that employee can enter that room;
  - If an employee has Attribute Alpha set to `X`, Beta set to`NULL` and the room has [Alpha=X -> `No`] that employee can't enter that room;
  - If an employee has Attribute Alpha set to `X`, Beta set to `A`, the room has [Alpha=X -> `No`] and [Beta=A -> `Yes`] that employee can enter that room, and finally
  - If an employee has Attribute Alpha set to `X`, Beta set to `A`, the room has [Alpha=X -> `No`] and [Beta=A -> `No`] that employee can't enter that room

My problem is: I have a giant if statement inside a loop that runs over the rooms to list the available rooms to the employee. Could anyone suggest a new look over it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
master_access = {}
for each employee in employees
    access = {}

    for each room in rooms
        if employee_has_access(employee, room)
            access.add(room)

    master_access.add(access)

return master_access
```

You could do something like

```
for each room in rooms
    if room.Alpha then alpha_rooms.add(room)
    if room.Beta.A then beta_a_rooms.add(room)
    else if room.Beta.B then beta_b_rooms.add(room)
    else if room.Beta.C then beta_c_rooms.add(room)

master_access = {}
for each employee in employees do
    access = {}
    if employee.Alpha == 'X' then access = access union alpha_rooms
    if employee.Beta == 'A' then access = access union beta_a_rooms
    else if employee.Beta == 'B' then access = access union beta_b_rooms
    else if employee.Beta == 'C' then access = access union beta_c_rooms
    master_access.add(access)

return master_access
```

The first sample - maybe what you are doing - is `O(er)` in the number of employees and rooms, whereas the second is more like `O(e + r)` (or, at least, could be made more like that if you're willing to pre-compute all six room lists and add one layer of nesting in the second loop to choose each employee's room list directly).